# How can i upload a zip folder on FTP server from my local drive using put command of ant tool

Tags: ant

in my lacal drive i created a zip folder whom i want to upload at FTP server by using the put command of ANT.pls give me some idea...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know if you're meaning this but check the Apache Commons library.
http://commons.apache.org/net/index.html

Would be something like:

```
    import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.*;

...

...

FTPClient ftp = new FTPClient();
        ftp.connect(FTP_HOST);
        ftp.login(FTP_USER, FTP_PASS);
        ftp.changeWorkingDirectory(FTP_PATH);
        ftp.setFileTransferMode(FTPClient.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileName);
        ftp.storeFile(fileName,fis);
        ftp.logout();
```

Comment: will u pls tell me that how can i put my code within <target name="" depends=""> <put .............all the parameters like username password local foldername   remote folder name   ,...../> </target>

Comment: Oh excuse me, didn't understand the question.
If you're developing a web app you can use a servlet and read all the params from the web.xml file.
If it's a local app I think you should use a conf file and read them from there.